# Inject generic DAO into Service (Spring 4)

Tags: java, spring, generics, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I'm looking for a solution to inject a generic DAO into a service.

More specifically, I'm looking for a way to inject a generic User DAO into a login Service.

In my case they are :

1. Multiple types of User which all inherits from `class User`
2. Foreach type of User there is a related DAO which inherits from
   `GenericUserDao<T extends User>`.

My first idea was to declare my service and inject my DAO like follows :

```
public class LoginService<DAO extends GenericUserDao<? extends User>> {
    @Autowired
    DAO userDao;
}

[...]

// declaration
@Autowired
LoginService<SpecialUserDao> userService;
```

But when doing this, Spring injects a GenericUserDao into my LoginService, and NOT a SpecialUserDao.

Thus, I tried to remove the `@Autowired` annotation on the userDao field and simply declare my LoginService as :

```
public class LoginService<DAO extends GenericUserDao<? extends User>> {
    DAO userDao;
}

[...]

// declaration
@Autowired
LoginService<SpecialUserDao> userService;
```

But then nothing ends up being injected and I logically get a NullPointerException when calling a DAO method.

What would be the proper way to inject my DAO ?

Comment: Did you tried `@Named`?

Comment: Not sure how that would help. The whole idea is to be able to have a common login service class for all users, and then create several instances of it with a specific DAO given as an argument (LoginService<SpecialUserDao> userService).